# MD5 brute-force attack - efficient multithreaded implementation

Tags: c++, multithreading, md5, brute-force

I want to implement a multithreaded MD5 brute-force attack algorithm (in C++). I know about Rainbow tables and dictionaries, but I'm not going to implement the most efficient MD5 cracker, just interested in brute-force algorithm

The problem is how to distribute all password variations of all available lengths between threads. For example, to restore a password containing only lower-case characters from 4 to 6 symbols we should look over N=26^4+26^5+26^6=321254128 combinations (according to variation with repetitions formula, Vnk = n^k)

So that distribute all permutations in equial parts between, for example 8 threads, we should know every (N/8)*t variation, where t=(1..7). And take notice, these variationa have different length (4,5,6), and variations of 4-5 symbols could be pushed to the same thread with some number of 6-symbols variations

Does anybody know, how that algorithm is implemented in "real-world" brute-force applications? Maybe some kind of thread-pool?

Answer (score 2):

The approach I find quite flexible is to spawn threads running the following code:

```
void thread_fn() {
    PASSWORD_BLOCK block;
    while (get_next_password_block(&block) {
        for (PASSWORD password in block) {
            if (verify_password(password)) set_password_found(password);
        }
    }
}
```

Typically, if code is well optimised, you will spawn as many threads as active cores; however in some cases launching more threads than cores can provide some performance gain (this points to sub-optimal code optimisation).

`get_next_password_block()` is where all locking and synchronisation is done. This function is responsible for keeping track of password list/range, incrementing password, etc.

Why use `PASSWORD_BLOCK` and not just a single password? Well, MD5 is a very fast algorithm, so if we will call `get_next_password_block()` for each password then overhead of locking/incrementing will be extreme. Besides, SIMD instructions allow us to perform bulk MD5 computations (4 passwords at a time), so we want a fast and efficient way to get a sizeable chunk of passwords to reduce overhead.

Particular size of the block depends on CPU speed and algorithm complexity; for MD5 I would expect it to be on the order of millions passwords.

Comment: So you advice to generate a block of passwords for every thread? Doesn't it produce high memory consumption with a large number of allocations?

Comment: You can (and should) allocate memory just once (per thread) and then re-use it. Furthermore, for brute-force attacks `PASSWORD_BLOCK` can actually be very simple and small, e.g. holding just a starting password and password count (i.e. not holding all the passwords).

Comment: Make sense, will consider

Comment: Anyway, is it some method to check N passwords per thread? I'm thinking about spawning threads per some "low-order" variations, i.e. for N symbols password create a separate thread to look over last 4 symbols variations. For example: AAAA____: 1st thread, AAAB____: 2nd thread, ...

Comment: Creating a thread is an expensive operation, so if performance matters then you should re-use existing ones. Note that you can achieve behaviour similar to what you're proposing by having `get_next_password_block()` return "AAAA____", "AAAB____", "AAAC____", etc.

Comment: I found the better way. I need just convert decimal number of variation to the radix generated by charset, i.e. for charset 'abc': 0 = a, 1 = b, 2 = c, 3 = ba, ... This does not require creating a lot of threads and memory reallocations

Answer (score 1):

The "correct" way of doing this would be to have a pool of workers (equal to the number of CPU cores, either not counting hyperthread cores, or counting all of them as "one") and a lockfree FIFO queue to which you submit groups of a hundred thousand or so tasks. This gives an acceptable balance between synchronization overhead and load balancing.
The trick is to divide work into relatively small groups, so the time when only one thread remains doing the last group is not too long (no parallelism there!), but at the same time not make the groups *too small* so you are bound by synchronization / bus contention. MD5 is pretty fast, so a few ten thousand to hundred thousand work items should be fine.

However, given the concrete problem, that's actually overkill. Way too complicated.

There are 26 times more 5-letter passwords than there are 4- letter passwords, and 26 times more 6-letter passwords than there are 5-letter ones, and so on. In other words, the longest password length has **by far** the biggest share in the total number of combinations. All 4,5,6 digit combinations together only make up about 3.9% of the combinations of all 7-digit combinations. In other words, they are totally insiginificant. **96% of the total runtime** is within the 7 digit combinations, no matter what you do with the rest. It is even more extreme if you consider letters and digits or capitalization.

Thus, you can simply fire up as many threads as you have CPU cores, and run all 4-digit combinations in one thread,  all 5-digit combinations in another one, and so on. That's not great, but it is good enough since nobody will notice a difference anyway.
Then simply partition the possible 7-digit combinations into `num_thread` equal-sized ranges, and have each thread that is finished with its initial range continue with that one.
Work will not always be perfectly balanced, but it will be during 96% of the runtime. And, it works with the absolute minimum of task management (none) and synchronization (merely need to set a global flag to exit when a match was found).

Since you cannot expect perfect load balancing even if you do perfect, correct task scheduling (since thread scheduling is in the hands of the operating system, not yours), this should be very close to the "perfect" approach.

Alternatively, you could consider firing up one extra thread which does the entire all-but-longest range of combinations (the "insignificant 3%") and partition the rest equally. This will cause a few extra context switches during startup, but on the other hand makes the program logic even simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Manual partitioning of a task to worker threads is not efficient from both view: the effort spent and the resulting load balance. Modern processors and OSes add to the imbalance even of what initially looks like very balanced workload due to:

- cache misses: one thread can hit cache, another can suffer from the cache miss spending up to thousands cycles per memory load operation where the same load can be performed in a few cycles.
- Turbo-boost, power-management, core-parking features. Both processor itself and OS can manage frequency and availability of computing units contributing to the imbalance.
- Thread preemption: there are other processes running in modern multitasking operation systems which can temporarily interrupting execution flow of a thread.

Modern work-stealing scheduling algorithms are quite efficient in mapping and load-balancing of even imbalanced work to worker threads: you just describe where you have the potential parallelism and task scheduler assigns it to the available resources. Work-stealing is a distributed approach which does not involve one shared state (e.g. iterator) and thus has no bottlenecks.

Check out [cilk](/questions/tagged/cilk), [tbb](/questions/tagged/tbb), or [ppl](/questions/tagged/ppl) for more information about implementations of such scheduling algorithms.
Moreover, they are friendly to nested and recursive parallel constructs like:

```
void check_from(std::string pass) {
    check_password(pass);
    if(pass.size() < MAX_SIZE)
        cilk_for(int i = 0; i < syms; i++)
            check_from(pass+sym[i]);
}
```